# Laravel 5 many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have bellow code:

```
$my_array = array(1,2,3);
$application->computerSkills()->sync($my_array);
```

now if i use `dd($application->computerSkills)` it return data, but if i change above code to the following, it returns empty.

```
$current_skills = $application->computerSkills;

$my_array = array(1,2,3);
$application->computerSkills()->sync($my_array);
```

Then result of `dd($application->computerSkills)` is empty.
So why, and how to solve?

***Note***: *with `detach()` and `attach()` also has the same problem.*

***Note***: *it is only in a situation, that this application has not yet any computer skill, and it is the first time.*

***Note***: *but it insert in table.*

Bellow code is the relation ship functions:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function applications(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Applications\Application');
}

public function computerSkills(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Applications\ComputerSkill');
}
```

and table structure:
`applications`

id

`computer_skills`

id

`application_computer_skill`

application_id

computer_skill_id

Comment: what is `$current_skills` doing here?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki I need it for using in log of its previous data.

Comment: I guess your `computerSkill` table does not have records with ids provided in `$my_array`, so when you use `sync()`, it removes previous records and adds nothing!

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki But in table it insert that array.

Comment: Please paste your relation functions.

Comment: @prateekkathal I have pasted my relation functions.

Comment: @jones Can you paste your tables as well. I need to know if models are properly mapped to their tables and foreign keys.

Comment: I'm not sure, but as I think, the problem, is that `computerSkills` is empty, even if you do the sync. Sync creates a connection between your application and computer skills. It will create records in the pivot table, no mater, that the skills are exists or not. When you want to check the `$application->computerSkills`, and there is no records on the other end, nothing will return. It doesn't matter, that you have populated the pivot table with `array(1,2,3)`. It will be used in a `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` query. Which will return nothing, if it not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your model relationships as:

```
public function applications(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Applications\Application', 'application_computer_skill', 'application_id', 'computer_skill_id');
}

public function computerSkills(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Applications\ComputerSkill', 'application_computer_skill', 'computer_skill_id', 'application_id');
}
```

and then, use your code:

```
$my_array = array(1,2,3);
$application->computerSkills()->sync($my_array);
```